# Multiple Metal shaders with different language versions in one project

Tags: macos, metal

I'm trying to include multiple Metal shaders in my Xcode project which have different language versions, but I'm unable to figure out how to do it.

I'm trying to do this, so I can support the latest features when available and drop back when not.

In the project's settings I can only find a general specifier for the Metal language revision. I also can't find anything in the MSL reference manual to specify it inside the file.

Is this even possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should check feature availability based on the GPU family https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlfeatureset

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not enough. If I run my app on 10.11 it terminates with the message that the fragment shader is compiled with language version 1.2 instead of 1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode, go to the Build Phases for the target which builds your app. Disclose the compile sources. Select a .metal file. Double-click in the right-hand Compiler Flags column to edit it. Enter `-std=osx-metal1.2` or similar. That specific shader source file will be compiled with that language.

I found this compiler flag by comparing the build transcripts of builds with various settings for the target-wide build setting.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I'm looking for!